# Is there any harm to setting the same static ip for eth0 and eth1?

Tags: linux, ethernet, static-ip

I'm configuring a Fedora server to use a static ip (although this question should apply to any Linux server). Unfortunately, I don't have much control over which of the two ethernet ports gets used. I was wondering if there was any harm in configuring both ports to the same ip as long as I know only one port will be used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A cleaner option would be to setup a bridge between the two interfaces, then assigning the static address to the bridge. This way you can use either port, and it works as a bridge too.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no harm as long as you are **sure** that only one will be in use at a time.

Side note: You should really steer clear from Fedora on a server. It has a short support cycle and you have to upgrade OS versions once a year in order to get patches. CentOS is from the Red Hat family like Fedora, but has a much longer support cycle.

Comment: I appreciate you advice on what distribution to use. Unfortunately, in my situation, there just isn't time to do a wipe. It's one of those should-have-been-running-yesterday situations.